# keras failed to import

Tags: linux, python-3.x, keras

I installed in accordance with the official website, in the /home directory python interactive mode to import keras successfully, but in the /home other directory under the python interactive mode import keras does not find the module

[image]

Comment: Change to english path for try.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the wheel(.whl) package from the [pypi website](https://pypi.org/project/Keras/#files) and pip install it.

[wheel package](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/e8/eaff7a09349ae9bd40d3ebaf028b49f5e2392c771f294910f75bb608b241/Keras-2.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl)